# Adding a character to each second line at the beginning without replacing the first char (which is random)

Tags: regex, notepad

I have a kinda big file which looks like this:

```
100]
Armor=769       
101]
Armor=769       
102]
Armor=769       
103]
Armor=772       
104]
Armor=772       
108]
Armor=770       
109]
Armor=773       
110]
Armor=773       
114]
Armor=771       
115]
Armor=774       
116]
Armor=774       
242]
Armor=778       
243]
Armor=779
```

I've already been playing around with notepad++, that's how I got this result , but now I am STUCK. What i want is:  Add to every second line a [ , so `100]`, `101]` and `102]` are now enclosed in brackets.  I can't just search for "1" and replace with [1 , the numbers are random, and get a lot bigger. I guess I have to go with regex here, which is a problem, because I have no idea how!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i cant just search for "1" and replace with [1, the numbers are random

Then search for `\d` at the beginning of a line, capture it in group 1, and replace it with - `[$1`, where `$1` is the capture group.

Replace - `^(\d)` with `[$1`

Comment: @KevinK.. You're welcome :) Remember to mark the answer accepted after 10 minutes from now.

Comment: @KevinK.. And yes, Welcome to SO. :)

Answer (score 0):

Regex to match the 123] lines would be

```
^[[:space:]]*[0-9]+[[:space:]]*\][[:space:]]*$
```

Which means:

^  match must start at the begining of the line.
[[:space:]]* the outer [] means any single character inside the brackets the [:space:] is a posix expression meaning all space character tabs etc the * means 0 or more of the previous char
[0-9]+ means 1 or more digits between 0 and 9
[[:space:]]* as above
] a literal ]
[[:space:]]* as above
$ must match end of the line

Hope this helps